# Record major-faults caused by read from regular files

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, perf, page-fault

As far as I understand when `read`ing from a file descriptor kernel has to map the file into main memory and only then copy the region into the supplied buffer. It means the reading from a file that is not already in cache should cause major page fault. So I try to catch it as follows:

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("/home/xxxxx/test_mmap", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    char buf[] = "1234";
    int i = read(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    printf("%s%s\n", buf, strerror(errno));
}
```

I cleaned the file system cache with command

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

and ran

```
sudo perf stat -e major-faults:k ./bin
```

I got the result

```
Performance counter stats for './bin':

                 0      major-faults:k                                              

       0.002235652 seconds time elapsed
```

meaning that no major faults occurred in the kernel. I suppose I did something wrong with it since If I run `sudo perf stat -e major-faults ./bin` after cleaning caches on

```
int main(void){
    int fd = open("/home/xxxxx/test_mmap", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
    char buf[] = "1234";
    int i = read(fd, buf, strlen(buf));
    char *mapped_region = mmap(NULL, sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    mapped_region[0] = '0';
    printf("%c\n", mapped_region[0]);
}
```

I got the output

```
Performance counter stats for './bin':

                 0      major-faults                                                

       0.002411539 seconds time elapsed
```

Meaning that the major fault occurred while reading from the file but was not recorded with `-e major-faults:k`.

***Question***: How to record major page faults with `perf` caused by `read`ing from the file descriptor?

Comment: _As far as I understand when reading from a file descriptor kernel has to map the file into main memory and only then copy the region into the supplied buffer. It means the reading from a file that is not already in cache should cause major page fault._ — This is incorrect for Linux.  There have been operating systems where `read` was implemented internally via `mmap` but Linux is not one of them.

Comment: @zwol So this leads to the question: Why isn't major-fault occurred if I do `mmap` after reading from the file descriptor? If I just do `mmap` without `read`ing first the major-fault is recorded as expected. I clean cache before each of the experiment.

Comment: Because `read` primes the cache, so your `mmap` only suffers a minor fault.  The kernel _does_ copy from disk into cache and then from cache to the `read` buffer, it just doesn't use page faults to do the first step.

Comment: @zwol Are you sure minor fault is required in the case when `read`ing first then `mmap`? I would expect that `mmap` in that case simply returns the pointer to the already cached region (if exists) avoiding any kind of page-fault.

Comment: @zwol _The kernel does copy from disk into cache and then from cache to the read buffer, it just doesn't use page faults to do the first step._ Could you please expand a bit? How is it possible to copy from disk into cache without page faultting? Or the cache is a pre-faulted region internal to the kernel so even when calling to `mmap` the kernel copies data from the cache to the `mmap`ed region and then causing only minor fault. Is it correct?

Comment: I think the `major-faults` counter is for major faults that occur in the process's address space. Simply `read`ing a file does not make it part of the process's address space, but `mmap`ing the file records the pages as being part of the process's address space. The `mmap`ed pages will be faulted in as necessary as they are accessed by the process, but if they are already in the buffer cache, this will be a minor fault rather than a major fault.

Comment: @IanAbbott Can you explain what you mean by "buffer cache"? As far as I understood from what @zwol said Linux maintains some cache where the kernel caches file-related pages. So even when calling to `mmap` an additional copy is involved instead of simply returning a pointer to the cached region. Is that the buffer cache you were talking about?

Comment: [The buffer cache](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/buffer-cache.html) uses unused system memory to cache the contents of recently accessed blocks read from or written to block devices. It is _block-related_ rather than _file-related_, but files may be backed by block devices. `mmap` maps blocks of a file to pages of virtual address space in the process. The blocks may or may not be paged in to the process memory and may or may not be in the buffer cache. After it is paged in, it will be in both the process memory and the buffer cache, but sharing the same page of physical memory.

Comment: @IanAbbott Very interesting, did not know about it, really. Now it is clear why minor-faults only occurs. Thank you.

Comment: @IanAbbott: the kernel's cache of file contents is the "page cache" (which you can map into user-space with `mmap`).   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache.  If Linux still has "buffer caches" for block-device I/O, that's something else.

Comment: @PeterCordes So in addition to the kernel's cache which I get pointers to when calling to `mmap` it is possible to have buffer cache which as sort of another cache level. Is it correct?

Comment: No.  I did more research (https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics#Page_Cache_or_Buffer_Cache); "buffer cache" is something the kernel *used* to have, before Linux 2.4.  In modern Linux, they're combined and there is only the page cache.  (Which buffers I/O to block devices, as well as holding file contents.)  Basically all disk caching is in the page cache.  (Filesystem metadata like directory structure can be cached in the VFS cache as well, so the filesystem-specific blocks don't have to be re-decoded to traverse directories.)